# Cannot convert source type to System.Nullable<double>

Tags: c#, angularjs

Here's my script:

```
public PlainBrgDataSummaryComplete SummaryComputationPerTransSQLite(long    ProgramID)
{
    PlainBrgDataSummaryComplete result = new  PlainBrgDataSummaryComplete();
    DataSet dataSet = GetPlainBrgDataSQLite(ProgramID);

    var abcde  = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
        .AsEnumerable()
        //.Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) >= startOfWeek1 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) < endOfWeek1.AddDays(1))
       .GroupBy(a => 1)
        .Select(d =>
            new PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans
            {
                transactionWk6 = d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))

            }
        ).FirstOrDefault();

    result.totaltransaction = new PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans
    {
        transactionWk6 = abcde;
    };

    return result;
}
```

I'm getting the error  - Cannot convert source type to `System.Nullable<double>`.  Specifically on the part `transactionWk6 = abcde`;

Comment: what is the type of transactionWk6 in PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans class?

Comment: public double? transactionWk6 { get; set; }

Comment: you are getting the error in RunTime right ?

Comment: you're converting `PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans` class to `double?`, that is not allowed by default.

Comment: That's correct when debugging.

Comment: Please check Mihail Stancescu answer that should solve the issue i suppose

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? That's a pretty weird query, particularly grouping by a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abcde` is already a `PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans` type since you are projecting the `select` statement to it.

Try to use it like this:

```
result.totaltransaction = abcde;
return result;
```

Comment: What if I do have another var:

    var fghi = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
                .AsEnumerable()
                //.Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) >= startOfWeek1 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) < endOfWeek1.AddDays(1))
               .GroupBy(a => 1)
                .Select(d =>
                    new PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans
                    {
                        transactionWk5 = d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))

                    }
                ).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: How can I include it in the return result.  I tried this and it only returned 1

 result.totaltransaction = abcde;
            result.totaltransaction = fghi;

            return result;

Comment: It will still be the same: you are projecting the `select` statement into a `PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans` object and that's what you have to return in your method.

Comment: You have multiple linq queries you want to return? Or is it a single query that produces an enumeration?

Comment: I tried this and it only returned the last on:

 result.totaltransaction = abcde; 
result.totaltransaction = fghi; 

return result;

Comment: multiple link queries to return

Comment: Ok, the assuming that `result.totaltransaction` is a collection you can add the result to that collection and return once you are done. Also you can combine this in a single linq query though.

Comment: Can you tell how?  Here's my totaltransaction in class: 
public PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans totaltransaction { get; set; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105636/discussion-between-bot-sundi-and-mihail-stancescu).

Answer (score 0):

Mihail Stancescu should solve the issue. However considering your return type you dont need the extra assignment. you can change code like below

```
public PlainBrgDataSummaryComplete SummaryComputationPerTransSQLite(long    ProgramID)
{
DataSet dataSet = GetPlainBrgDataSQLite(ProgramID);

return dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
    .AsEnumerable()
    //.Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) >= startOfWeek1 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) < endOfWeek1.AddDays(1))
   .GroupBy(a => 1)
    .Select(d =>
        new PlainBrgDataSummaryTrans
        {
            transactionWk6 = d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))

        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

}

Comment: return type is `PlainBrgDataSummaryComplete`.